# WSImport bindings for two WSDLs with the same namespace

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, wsimport

I am writing a client that leverages two separate WSDLs from a third party. These two WSDLs have the exact same namespaces. So, I created binding files to put the objects generated from the two WSDLs into separate packages to avoid conflicts. However, there are a few common elements between these two WSDLs that share the exact same definition. Having these objects be generated into separate packages is not desirable since I'd like to share them. I have been unable to find any way to do this using binding files. The closest I got was to pull those shared elements out of the WSDLs and put them in a new XSD, change the targetNamespace of this XSD, and then target that namespace in the binding file to put it into a different package. The issue with this approach is that now the namespace of the generated common objects is different, so it doesn't serialize properly when calling the actual service.

The shared elements in question look like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="OperationResult">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MessageID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Results" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfCommandResult"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="OperationResult" nillable="true" type="tns:OperationResult"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfCommandResult">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="CommandResult" nillable="true" type="tns:CommandResult"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="ArrayOfCommandResult" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfCommandResult"/>
    <xs:complexType name="CommandResult">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EntityID" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="EntityType" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ExchangeID" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Code" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Reason" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="CommandResult" nillable="true" type="tns:CommandResult"/>
```

and they are just defined inside of the

```
 <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.mypartnercompany.com/stuff/2013/06"
                   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Is there anything that I can do to get these common objects to generate to a separate package so I can share them between the two services, without having to change the namespace myself?